# Response Codes 404 from Android App and 200 from Browser with the same URL

Tags: android, https

Please, I need help in resolving this issue. I am trying to access a url from my android app but I am getting response `code 404` When I try the same url on a browser, I will get response `code 200`. See A screenshot and my codes below:

**SCREENSHOT:**
[image: See in the Logcat, the lines with red arrows.]

**ApiService:**

```
interface EskoolApiService {
    ...........

    @POST("search/")
    suspend fun searchForCourse(
        @QueryMap filters: Map<String, Int>,
        @Query("search") searchTerm: String
    ): SearchedCourses

}
```

**NOTE:** *Other routes are working fine except the one above.*

**MyViewModel:**

```
       val searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class, FlowPreview::class)
    val fetchedText = searchText.debounce(1000)
        .filterNotNull()
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest {
            searchForCourse(it)
        }

    private fun searchForCourse(query: String): Flow<SearchedCourses> {
        var courses = SearchedCourses(courses = listOf(SearchedCourse(title ="No Course Found!")))
        if (query.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return flowOf(courses)
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _status.value = ApiResponseStatus.LOADING
            try {
                courses = courseDataRepository.courseSearch(query)
                _status.value = ApiResponseStatus.SUCCESS
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _status.value = ApiResponseStatus.ERROR
                _errorMessage.value = e.message ?: "An Error Occurred"
                Log.i("TAG-searchForCourse", "query from server: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
        return flowOf(courses)
    }
```

**DataRepository:**

```
    interface CourseDataRepository {
    .........
    suspend fun courseSearch(searchTerm: String): SearchedCourses
}
```

**DefaultDataRepository:**

```
   class DefaultCourseDataRepository(private val retrofitService: EskoolApiService): CourseDataRepository {
            ............
            override suspend fun courseSearch(searchTerm: String): SearchedCourses {
                    val pageSize = mapOf("page" to 1, "page_size" to 10)
                    return retrofitService.searchForCourse(pageSize, searchTerm)
                 }
   }
```

Comment: If you have browsed the site you got cookies and these cookies are automatically transmitted when browse the URL. Use curl or a different non-webbrowser to test if you also get an HTTP 404.